# system report of emedded system created through Xilinx XPS

Tags: xilinx

I'm doing project of shadow detection. It uses Xilinx XPS tool to create the embedded system.Once the system created is there any way i can check how many logic gates are produced and how they are configured. 
Is there any option to retrive this information in XPS tool..?

Answer (score 0):

There's a report file produced which tells you how many LUTs and Flipflops andthe like are used.

There's not a direct equivalent to actual gates as each LUT would be different depending on its acutal function in the design